# Migration Angular 5 to 6 - 'ng update' hanging and do nothing

Tags: angular, migration, angular6

I'm migration Angular from 5 to 6.

After added latest angular-cli to my project i try to execute 'ng update'.

But absolutely nothing happens (the console hangs and i have to cancel it).

ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@angular/cli                 6.0.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         6.2.0
typescript                   2.9.1
webpack                      3.12.0
```

Does somebody had the same issue?

Comment: I noticed it does take a while, however it does _eventually_ let you know which packages can be updated

Comment: @Und3rTow Thx for advice. After waiting for 10 minutes i get "read ECONNRESET". Hmmmm???

Comment: That's an npm issue, what version of node are you running?

Comment: I'm running node v8.9.3

Comment: @Und3rTow Thx, updated node to 10 - and it's running.

Comment: i'm behind corporate proxy

Comment: the problem is definitely the corporate proxy

Comment: It is incredibly slow... wait longer (10 minutes before you see any action?).  Also run as Admin

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the following (in this sequence!):

- Install Angular/CLI 6 global: `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- Install Angular/CLI 6 local:  `npm install @angular/cli`
- Install dependent packages for Angular/CLI 6:  `ng update @angular/cli`
- Install dependent packages for angular/core 6:  `ng update @angular/core`
- Install anything else: `npm install`

Next, check and see if it works.  I use `ng build --prod`.  That command shakes the tree pretty hard.

Comment: yes, i use yarn. The first two run, but 'ng update' doing nothing

Comment: after retrying many times, it worked when running VSCode as administrator https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11049, But it could be something related to angular remote site slowness.